# Finding partial keywords / keyphrases in a list

Tags: c#

I am trying to find a way to look up a single word or multiple words from a list. The user inputs the word(s), and information about that item is fetched from the ItemList, based on the name.

For Example:

```
PriceList[0].name="Black Sheep"
PriceList[1].name="Black Horse"
PriceList[2].name="White Horse"
PriceList[3].name="White Sheep"
```

are some items in the list, where PriceList is an ItemList, that looks like:

```
public class ItemList
{
public int amount { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public int buyprice { get; set; }
public int sellprice { get; set; }
public int stock { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I want my code to do:

- Case 1: User asks for "Black"        : Return indices 0, 1.
- Case 2: User asks for "White"        : Return 2, 3.
- Case 3: User asks for "Horse"        : Return 1, 2.
- Case 4: User asks for "Sheep"        : Return 0, 3.
- Case 5: User asks for "Black Horse"  : Return 1.
- Case 6: User asks for "White Horse"  : Return 2.
- Case 7: User asks for "Whit Horse"   : Return 2 but not 1.
- Case 8: User asks for "Red Horse"    : Return 1, 2.

etc.

I currently have:

```
int nickindex = PriceList.FindIndex(x => x.name.Split().Contains(typeToAdd));
```

where typeToAdd is the user input string.

However, this only returns one index, and it fails for cases 5 and up.

How can I loop over all indices to find them? I also need to be able to search for phrases rather than words. Lastly, I need to search within the words if no match was found (Case 7)

I have looked at [Algorithm to find keywords and keyphrases in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005687/algorithm-to-find-keywords-and-keyphrases-in-a-string) but it doesn't help me much.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure your examples are correct? Cases 6,7, and 8 seem inconsistent to me

Comment: Case 6: If there's a phrase that matches exactly the user's input, return only that but not separate word matches.
Case 7: If no exact phrase is found, do word-matching (returns 1, 2). If no exact word is found for a word, search within the words and filter the results. The final result returns the index of "white horse" when "whit horse" is the input, and excludes the "black horse".
Case 8: Same as case 7, but since "red" is not found anywhere, as a word or piece of a word, return the phrases that contain the word "horse". e.g. "did you mean one of these?"

Hope this clears it up a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the overload of `Select` which gives you the index to initialize an anonymous type:

```
string[] words = "Black Horse".Split();
IEnumerable<int> indices = PriceList
    .Select((pl, index) => new { pl, index })
    .Where(x => words.Intersect(x.pl.name.Split()).Any())
    .Select(x => x.index);
```

I'm using `Enumerable.Intersect` to check if one of the words in the input string matches one of the word in the name.

If you want to order descending by the number of matches:

```
IEnumerable<int> indices = PriceList
    .Select((pl, index) => new 
    { 
        pl, 
        index, 
        matches = words.Intersect(pl.name.Split()).Count()
    })
    .Where(x => x.matches > 0)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.matches)
    .Select(x => x.index);
```

However, this doesn't cover your last cases since it does not compare similarity of the words. You could use Levenshtein algorithm for this. Your rules are also not that clear on 6-8.

Comment: I imagine you could do an order by the number of words that match, and then select the top ranked ones out of that? Still wouldn't work for 7 but...

Comment: @Jeff: i have edited my answer to show a way to order the result by the number of matches.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what I was looking for, and it works for most of the cases. I will look at the Levenshtein algorithm for distances.