# PHP proc_open won't work - gives me "Missing handle qualifier in array"

Tags: php, windows, xampp, proc-open

> Warning: proc_open(): Missing handle qualifier in array in C:\...\updatedots.php on line 102

I'm trying to open notepad the close it after 2 seconds. This is my code:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe" => "r"),
    1 => array("pipe" => "w"),
    2 => array("file" => "logs/errors.txt")
);

// Create child and start process
$child = array("process" => null, "pipes" => array());
$child["process"] = proc_open("notepad.exe > nul 2>&1", $descriptorspec, $child["pipes"]);
```

Any idea what this error means and what causes it?

Comment: Then what Stephan said. Regardless, my comment was an attempt to prompt you into providing more explicit information in your questions in future.

Comment: Just to clarify, since my code only contains one instance of `proc_open` I assumed it would be obvious that the error message is referring to it. That's how I thought of it anyway

Comment: What I was trying to get at is that we prefer you post minimal _testcases_, and the error messages should come from those testcases.

Comment: The error message clearly doesn't come from the posted code, as the posted code doesn't contain 102 lines ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not `0 => array("pipe" => "r")` but `0 => array("pipe", "r")` ^^

Additionally, when giving a filename you need to specify the mode to use. This works on my machine:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("file", "logs/errors.txt", "a") ); 
// Create child and start process 
$child = array("process" => null, "pipes" => null); 
$child["process"] = proc_open("notepad.exe > nul 2>&1", $descriptorspec, $child["pipes"]);
```